# Why Time Complexity of This Algorithm is O(n^5)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Can anyone explain to me why the time complexity of this algorithm is O(n^5), the answer is given but the reason its not.

```
static void rub(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j = i; j< i*i; j++){
            if (j%i == 0){
                for (int k=0; k<j; k++){
                    System.out.println("*");
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: What do you think it is and what's your reasoning?

Comment: The answer is given by the author and i have to explain it but that if statement confuses me

Comment: Start by removing `count` since it's unused and irrelevant. After that, why not try some inputs and reason a bit about it? Clearly, the `i*i` and `j%i` points are critical, because `j%i` determines how many times the innermost `k` loop runs and `i*i` is also going to impact complexity.

Comment: well ive been trying but cant seem to find a solution and i need to assign this tonight

Comment: Share your efforts here as an edit to the post. See [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).